# StateCode, CountryCode fields not available in SalesforceDX

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, compile-error, country-and-state

I am trying to switch to DX but noticed that the CountryCode and StateCode are no longer being recognized by Salesforce in DX environment. Trying to reference those fields gives me an invalid field error.

Has anybody else experienced this? Is this something that SF is planning to address?

Comment: Did you enable [State&Country Picklists](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf)? This feature must be active for these fields to show. Only posting as comment since it's not clear if that's the issue.

Comment: Just as a note to Adrian's comment: with Salesforce DX when you create a scratch org you need to specify which features are enabled when it is created. This includes almost every setting you can enable on the setup (multi-currency, as another example).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Let me dig a little deeper into it and I will report back!

Comment: Here's a link to the Screatch Org Definition File: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm I couldn't see if there is an option to enable State&Country Picklists there, but I think you can enable it after the org is created.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira - I couldn't find anything in the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm to enable this from within the configuration. Do you have an idea of there could be some additional documentation that perhaps I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you enable [State and Country Picklists](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf), as this feature must be enabled for StateCode and CountryCode fields to show up.

Comment: Just tested, that's it! Thanks I completely forgot about doing this!