# Apex compiler claims that "ShippingStateCode" does not exist, but the documentation says it is always present

Tags: apex, documentation, address, compound-fields

> Variable does not exist: ShippingStateCode

While trying to compile a code with the following variable defined, I'm getting the error above.

```
private static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> addressMapping = new Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>{
    'street' => Account.ShippingStreet,
    'city' => Account.ShippingCity,
    'state' => Account.ShippingStateCode,
    'zip_code' => Account.ShippingPostalCode
};
```

However, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm) says that the state code is (emphasis mine):

> The ISO state code for the address. For example, this field is known as MailingStateCode on Contact. **StateCode is always available on compound address fields, whether or not state and country picklists are enabled in your organization.**

Is the documentation wrong, or am I not seeing something obvious?

Comment: What API version is the code that you're trying to save using?

Comment: I'm using the latest, 50.0.

Comment: It's only enabled if you turn on country/state picklists.

Comment: See also: [StateCode, CountryCode fields not available in SalesforceDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/205465/2995)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Apex field reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm) for Account shows it as `ShippingState` and doesn't expose `ShippingStateCode`.

[image]

The [API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) exposes both:

[image]

It appears Apex doesn't expose the ISO State Code for either the Shipping or Billing addresses by default. The same issue exists for the ISO Country Code.

I haven't been able to find any documentation, but it might be related to toggling the ["State and Country Picklists"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=5) setting. The example code in [Access the state and country picklist through Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338321&type=1&mode=1) suggests the picklist values become associated with the `StateCode` field, albeit on the `User` object.

This seems more definitive in [Impact on Apex code if State and Country Picklists feature is enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329128&type=1&mode=1) (my emphasis):

> - Developers need to append the word 'code' to the picklist fields in their Apex Code, when the above feature is Enabled.
> - For instance, **instead of using 'mailingstate,' developers will now have to use 'mailingstatecode'** to retrieve the old values in a trigger.

In the [Address Compound Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm) documentation you linked to and highlighted it does say:

> StateCode is always available on compound address fields, **whether or not state and country picklists are enabled in your organization**.

While that may be true for the API, it doesn't appear to work that way in Apex.

Comment: If this is working as designed, I'm dumbfounded by this particular difference in implementation. Also surprised I haven't run into it myself over the years...

Comment: I think it is one of those things where the org gets setup and it never really changes of the years. I'm also kind of surprised I haven't run into it with managed packages needing to set the StateCode rather than the State. It might just be that I've never run into the setting being enabled. I might need to spin up some scratch orgs to test it.